# VSTS - Deleting previous deployments during a release

Tags: powershell, azure, continuous-integration, azure-devops, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I'm working for an Azure project where the deployments can only be made using the ARM templates from Visual Studio CI and we have only read access to the Azure Portal.

Currently I'm getting the below error and can make no releases. I cannot delete deployments from Portal either since I have only permission to configure build and release phases, I was wondering if there is any phase I can create where the previous deployments are deleted.

So far I tried couple of things like using inline PowerShell command *Remove-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment* , deleting resource group of type *Microsoft.Resouces/deployments* before the resource deployment phase but non of them worked.

> [error]Creating the deployment 'azuredeploy-2017721-715' would exceed the quota of '800'. The current deployment count is '800', please delete some deployments before creating a new one. Please see https://aka.ms/arm-deploy for usage details.

Comment: Will this help? https://vijredblog.wordpress.com/2016/12/29/creating-the-deployment-would-exceed-the-quota-of-800-azure-error-resolution/

Comment: _Login-AzureRmAccount_ command opens a popup for logging in hence it seems that cannot be used during a deployment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the Azure PowerShell task. It takes care of authentication for you -- no need to call `Login-AzureRmAccount`.

Comment: I previously used PowerShell++ task to write the script inline but did not work. However putting it in a script file and using Azure PowerShell task did work indeed. I simply used `Get-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment -ResourceGroupName MyResourceGroupName | Remove-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment` now it's deleting all. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a script that allows you to delete such deployments in a parallel manner. You can also use this for an Azure PowerShell task in Azure DevOps. If you have issues regarding authentication have a look here: [Azure credentials have not been set up or have expired, please run Connect-AzAccount](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54942499/azure-credentials-have-not-been-set-up-or-have-expired-please-run-connect-azacc)

```
Param(
    [string] 
    [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)]
    $subscriptionId,

    [string] 
    [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)]
    $tenantId,

    [string] 
    [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)]
    $resourceGroupName,

    [int] 
    [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)]
    $numberOfDeploymentsToKeep,

    [int] 
    [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)]
    $batchSize
)

try {
    $c = Get-AzContext
}
catch {
    $c = $null
}

if (!$c -or !$c.Account) {
    Connect-AzAccount -Subscription $subscriptionId -Tenant $tenantId
} else {
    Select-AzSubscription -Subscription $subscriptionId -Tenant $tenantId
}

# ----------------------------------
# Get Deployments
# ----------------------------------

#$dateBeforeDeleteDeployments = Get-Date -Year 2018 -Month 06 -Day 30
#$deploymentsToDelete = Get-AzResourceGroupDeployment -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName | Where-Object { $_.Timestamp -le $dateBeforeDeleteDeployments }

$currentDeployments = Get-AzResourceGroupDeployment -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName

$currentNumberOfDeployments = ($currentDeployments | Measure-Object).Count
$numberOfDeploymentsToRemove = $currentNumberOfDeployments - $numberOfDeploymentsToKeep

if ($numberOfDeploymentsToRemove -lt 0) {
    throw "Number of deployments to remove is < 0..."
} 
if ($numberOfDeploymentsToRemove -eq 0) {
    Write-Host "Number of deployments to remove is 0..."
    return
}

Write-Host "Number of Deployments to remove: '$numberOfDeploymentsToRemove'..."

$deploymentsToDelete = $currentDeployments | Sort-Object -Property Timestamp | Select-Object -First $numberOfDeploymentsToRemove

$deploymentsToDelete | ForEach-Object {$i=0; $j=0; $deploymentsToDeleteBatched=@{}} {
    if($i -ne $batchSize -and $deploymentsToDeleteBatched["Batch $j"]) { 
        $deploymentsToDeleteBatched["Batch $j"]+=$_
        $i+=1 
    }
    else {
        $i=1
        $j+=1
        $deploymentsToDeleteBatched["Batch $j"]=@($_)
    }
}

Write-Host "Created $($deploymentsToDeleteBatched.Count) batches..."

# ----------------------------------
# Execute deletion in parallel
# ----------------------------------
$jobNames = @()
foreach ($batchkey in $deploymentsToDeleteBatched.Keys) {
    $deploymentsToDeleteBatch = $deploymentsToDeleteBatched.$batchkey

    $logic = {
        Param(
            [object] 
            [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)]
            $ctx,

            [object] 
            [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)]
            $deploymentsToDeleteBatch,

            [string] 
            [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)]
            $resourceGroupName
        )

        foreach ($deploymentToDelete in $deploymentsToDeleteBatch) {
            $deploymentName = $deploymentToDelete.DeploymentName
            Remove-AzResourceGroupDeployment -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName -Name $deploymentName -DefaultProfile $ctx -ErrorAction Stop
            Write-Host "Deleted Deployment '$deploymentName' from '$($deploymentToDelete.Timestamp)'..."
        }  
    }

    $jobName = ([System.Guid]::NewGuid()).Guid
    $jobNames += $jobName
    $jobObject = Start-Job $logic -Name $jobName -ArgumentList (Get-AzContext), $deploymentsToDeleteBatch, $resourceGroupName
}

while (Get-Job -State "Running") {
    Write-Host "---------------------------------------------------------------"
    Write-Host "Jobs still running..."
    Get-Job | Format-Table
    Write-Host "---------------------------------------------------------------"
    Start-Sleep -Seconds 10
}

Write-Host "Jobs completed, getting output..."
Write-Host "---------------------------------------------------------------"

foreach ($jobName in $jobNames) {
    Write-Host "Output of Job '$jobName'..."
    Receive-Job -Name $jobName
    Write-Host "---------------------------------------------------------------"
}

Write-Host "Done..."
```