# Azure credentials have not been set up or have expired, please run Connect-AzAccount

Tags: azure, powershell, authentication, azure-devops, azure-authentication

Related to the following question ([Azure DevOps - Custom Task - PowerShell with Azure Authentification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54286763/azure-devops-custom-task-powershell-with-azure-authentification)) I am using now `Connect-AzAccount` to login by using a Azure DevOps Custom Task.

In the next step I want to run multiple jobs in parallel to first manipulate and then deploy certain Azure resources via templates. Working with AzureRM this worked without problems but after switching to Az I always get the error

> Your Azure credentials have not been set up or have expired, please
>   run Connect-AzAccount to set up your Azure credentials.

I already updated the Az modules to the most current version.

Here is how I do it:

**Authenticate**

```
try {
    $endpoint = Get-VstsEndpoint -Name $serviceName -Require
    if (!$endpoint) {
        throw "Endpoint not found..."
    }
    $subscriptionId = $endpoint.Data.SubscriptionId
    $tenantId = $endpoint.Auth.Parameters.TenantId
    $servicePrincipalId = $endpoint.Auth.Parameters.servicePrincipalId
    $servicePrincipalKey = $endpoint.Auth.Parameters.servicePrincipalKey

    $spnKey = ConvertTo-SecureString $servicePrincipalKey -AsPlainText -Force
    $credentials = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential($servicePrincipalId,$spnKey)

    Connect-AzAccount -ServicePrincipal -TenantId $tenantId -Credential $credentials
    Select-AzSubscription -SubscriptionId $subscriptionId -Tenant $tenantId

    $ctx = Get-AzContext
    Write-Host "Connected to subscription '$($ctx.Subscription)' and tenant '$($ctx.Tenant)'..."
} catch {
    Write-Host "Authentication failed: $($_.Exception.Message)..." 
}
```

**Deploy in parallel**

```
foreach ($armTemplateFile in $armTemplateFiles) {
    $logic = {
        Param(
            [object] 
            [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
            $ctx,

            [object] 
            [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
            $armTemplateFile,

            [string] 
            [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
            $resourceGroupName
        )

        ####################################################################
        # Functions
        function Format-ValidationOutput {
            param ($ValidationOutput, [int] $Depth = 0)
            Set-StrictMode -Off
            return @($ValidationOutput | Where-Object { $_ -ne $null } | ForEach-Object { @('  ' * $Depth + ': ' + $_.Message) + @(Format-ValidationOutput @($_.Details) ($Depth + 1)) })
        }

        ####################################################################
        # Logic

        # Some template manipulation


        $paramFileContent | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 100 | Set-Content -Path $paramTemplateFile.FullName
        $templateFileContent | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 100 | Set-Content -Path $armTemplateFile.FullName

        ####################################################################
        # Test Deployment
        $ErrorMessages = Format-ValidationOutput (Test-AzResourceGroupDeployment -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName `
                                                                                        -TemplateFile $armTemplateFile.FullName `
                                                                                        -TemplateParameterFile $paramTemplateFile.FullName `
                                                                                        -DefaultProfile $ctx)
        if ($ErrorMessages) {
            Write-Host '', 'Validation returned the following errors:', @($ErrorMessages), '', 'Template is invalid.'
        }
        else { # Deploy

            New-AzResourceGroupDeployment -Name (($armTemplateFile.Name).Split(".")[0] + ((Get-Date).ToUniversalTime()).ToString('MMddHHmm')) `
                                                -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName `
                                                -TemplateFile $armTemplateFile.FullName `
                                                -TemplateParameterFile $paramTemplateFile.FullName `
                                                -Force `
                                                -ErrorVariable ErrorMessages `
                                                -DefaultProfile $ctx
            if ($ErrorMessages) {
                Write-Host '', 'Template deployment returned the following errors:', @(@($ErrorMessages) | ForEach-Object { $_.Exception.Message.TrimEnd("`r`n") })
            }
        }
    }
    Start-Job $logic -ArgumentList (Get-AzContext), $armTemplateFile, $ResourceGroupName
}

While (Get-Job -State "Running")
{
    Start-Sleep 10
    Write-Host "Jobs still running..."
}

Get-Job | Receive-Job
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For some reason (I don't know) passing the context to a background job does not work anymore since moving to the Az modules (also with the most current version (1.4.0)). I tried either using `Save-AzContext` with `Import-AzContext` or getting the context via `Get-AzContext` and passing it to the background job (with `Set-AzContext` or directly using `-DefaultProfile` (this approach worked with the AzureRm modules)).

A workaround that works for me now is to authenticate each background job individually.

**For the job definition:**

```
foreach ($armTemplateFile in $armTemplateFiles) {
    $logic = {
        Param(
            [object] 
            [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
            $endpointInput,

            [object] 
            [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
            $armTemplateFile,

            [string] 
            [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
            $resourceGroupName
        )

        ###########################
        #Login
        Write-Host "Authenticating..."
        try {
            $endpoint = $endpointInput
            if (!$endpoint) {
                throw "Endpoint not found..."
            }
            $subscriptionId = $endpoint.Data.SubscriptionId
            $tenantId = $endpoint.Auth.Parameters.TenantId
            $servicePrincipalId = $endpoint.Auth.Parameters.servicePrincipalId
            $servicePrincipalKey = $endpoint.Auth.Parameters.servicePrincipalKey

            $spnKey = ConvertTo-SecureString $servicePrincipalKey -AsPlainText -Force
            $credentials = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential($servicePrincipalId,$spnKey)

            Connect-AzAccount -ServicePrincipal -TenantId $tenantId -Credential $credentials
            Select-AzSubscription -SubscriptionId $subscriptionId -Tenant $tenantId

            $ctx = Get-AzContext
            Write-Host "Connected to subscription '$($ctx.Subscription)' and tenant '$($ctx.Tenant)'..."
        } catch {
            Write-Host "Authentication failed: $($_.Exception.Message)..." 
        }
```

**For starting the job:**

```
Start-Job $logic -Name $jobName -ArgumentList $endpoint, $armTemplateFile, $ResourceGroupName
```

Answer (score -3):

I personally use this command:

```powersheell
Connect-AzureRmAccount
```

I first login **directly using the ISE console**, then the session is persisted and i can run any scripts without any issue (without using this command inside the script).

Hope it helps you.

**EDIT.**

I see you are also selecting subscription, this is the one I use.

```powersheell
Select-AzureRmSubscription -Subscription 'Subscription ID'
```